# Split a long question to multiple short questions. NLP

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, medical

Could anyone please suggest an good pretrained NLP model to split a long question to multiple short questions in medical healthcare domain.

Example 1-
Long Question -

```
Does the patient have a diagnosis of HIV / AIDS?
```

Answer -

```
1. Does the patient have a diagnosis of HIV?
2. Does the patient have a diagnosis of AIDS?
```

Example 2
Long Question -

```
Does the patient have CLL/SLL with del(17p)/TP53 mutation?
```

Answer-

```
1. Does the patient have CLL with del(17p)/TP53 mutation?
2. Does the patient have SLL with del(17p)/TP53 mutation?
```

Example 3

```
Does the patient have HCV/HIV or HBV/HCV co-infections?
```

Answer-

```
1. Does the patient have HCV co-infections?
2. Does the patient have HIV co-infections?
3. Does the patient have HBV co-infections?
4. Does the patient have HCV co-infections?
```

I tried using sentence transformers, paraphrasing and it did not worked for me.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no pretrained model to do this.

Comment: Any approach how to solve this use case? Is the conditions based code only the solution?

Comment: Afaik this is a quite complex problem in general. Can you assume that the separator between the possible conditions is always `/`? If yes it's quite easy and there's no NLP, it's just enumerating all the possible combinations. If no, e.g. it can be ' A or B', it can be 'does the patient have A? What about B?', etc., then it's another story which probably involves the dependency tree, maybe coreference resolution... much harder. In theory the dependency tree tells you where there is a disjunction or conjunction.